# Comparing directories and making changes according to last modified time in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Am trying to learn powershell in order to write this script but I have been unable to learn fast enough. I need a script in powershell to do the following:

1. Compare two directories, copy over any missing files or subdirectories.
2. During the compare, also copy the most recent file(by last modified time) to the reference object.
3. This script should essentially lead to two duplicate directories on different servers, both with the most up to date last modified files and sub dirs.

Here is a little of what I have come up with. All it does now is compares the two dirs and determines what is missing from each. It is pretty basic and no where near where it needs to be. Pointers would be greatly appreciated if they would help me along the way. Thanks.

```
$test1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\test1
$test2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\test2
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $test -DifferenceObject $test2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirements I would just use a straight robocopy.  You can call it from Powershell with the ampersand (call) operator:

```
& robocopy "C:\test1" "C:\test2" /e /dcopy:T
```

Here is a link with some examples: [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: This works great. Thank you. However, all files and sub dirs were copied except a ps1 script in the test1 dir. Any ideas. Plus thanks for the robocopy link!

Comment: It copied a .ps1 file fine for me, maybe the file is in-use?  Try adding the /v switch for verbose logging.

Comment: It is because it was in the ref. object. This command does not copy from the ref to the diff object. The robocopy gets me going though and I am going to try and figure this out. Appreciate all of the help on my first question on this site.